# pymongo not being installed in airflow docker container

Tags: mongodb, airflow, pymongo

when i run airflow UI and refresh it for refreshing the DAG, the error comes which says no module pymongo. So i have tried to put it in requirements.txt and use that by volumes. Also i have installed it in cli. But the error is not going.

Is there a proper way we can use the etl technique using python on the DAG.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install pymongo

import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = pymongo.MongoClient(---)
```

Kindly need suggestions on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your own Airlfow image with extra dependencies if the ones installed by default are not enough for you.

This is described in detail in the docuemntation - with plenty of examples and explanation on when and how you should build the image

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html